# JSON extracted data returned too many times

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a JSON with the following shape for ~50 `_source` entries:

```js
{
    "hits": [
        {
            "_source": {
                "name": "henry",
                "jobs": ["judge", "lawyer"]
            }
        },
        {
            "_source": {
                "name": "henry",
                "jobs": ["dev", "waitress"]
            }
        }
        // ...
    ]
}
```

I want to extract only the first item in `jobs` node, *i.e.* `judge, dev, ...` and tried the following:

```js
for (i in json.hits) 
{ 
    const jobExtract = json.hits[i]._source;        

    for (i=0; i<jobExtract.jobs.length; i++)
    { 
        const firstItem = jobExtract.jobs[0];
        console.log(firstItem);
    }
}
```

I can extract the first item but it appears multiple times:

```js
judge
judge
judge
dev
dev
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Why do your access `hits` inside `hits` like this `json.hits.hits`? The json seems to have only one `hits` at top level.

Comment: sorry, I edited.

Answer (score 2):

The first solution that pops up in my mind is using [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Considering:

```
const hits =  [
    {
   "_source": {
                "name": "henry",
                 "jobs" : [ "judge","lawyer"] },
     },
     {
   "_source": {
                "name": "henry",
                 "jobs" : [ "dev","waitress"] },
     }, ]

const result = hits.reduce((acc, item) => acc = [item._source.jobs[0], ...acc], []) 

console.log(result) // ["dev", "judge"]
```

Hope this helps